# how do you write an anchor program function that allows for a wallet address to be passed in from the client?

Tags: anchor

I am making an anchor program that sends SOL to a wallet address that I pass in through the client. How do I write the anchor program (in the lib.rs file) such that it allows for my frontend to input that address and sends the SOL to that address?

Answer (score 2):

Have your anchor program expect an account to be passed in the instruction.

For example:

```
#[program]
pub mod transfer_sol {
    use super::*;

    pub fn transfer_sol_with_cpi(
        ctx: Context<TransferSolWithCpi>, 
        amount: u64
    ) -> Result<()> {

        system_program::transfer(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                system_program::Transfer {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.recipient.to_account_info(),
                },
            ),
            amount,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_sol_with_program(
        ctx: Context<TransferSolWithProgram>, 
        amount: u64
    ) -> Result<()> {

        **ctx.accounts.payer
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;
        **ctx.accounts.recipient
            .to_account_info()
            .try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;
        
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferSolWithCpi<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    recipient: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferSolWithProgram<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is just an example, not checking data
    #[account(mut)]
    recipient: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is just an example, not checking data
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

I am expecting a recipient and payer account in order to send SOL within the program with the `TransferSolWithProgram` Account struct.

However, it may be easier for you to just use the SystemProgram from the client-side to send sol. Something like:

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

(async () => {
  const fromKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  const toKeypair = Keypair.generate();

  const connection = new Connection(
    "https://api.devnet.solana.com",
    "confirmed"
  );

  const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    fromKeypair.publicKey,
    LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  );

  await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);

  const lamportsToSend = 1_000_000;

  const transferTransaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: fromKeypair.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toKeypair.publicKey,
      lamports: lamportsToSend,
    })
  );

  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transferTransaction, [
    fromKeypair,
  ]);
})();
```

With instead of the `fromKeypair` and `toKeypair`, you have the signer and the recipient public key in `toPubkey` param.

Comment: so, if you were calling TransferSolWithProgram, how would you pass in the recipient's address "DAdbcE5SdqoQArf7V87pYR6jPNmTtEUbR2XeC1kAzZjh" from the client?

Comment: Yes as the recipient